# How to setup Flyway for snowflake on Windows

Tags: windows, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flyway

We are looking for auto deployment of database objects for snowflake. We came across flyway database migration tool and going through the documentation to perform the deployment to push the changes.

Does FLyway work with Snowflake. if yes, how can I use flyway from windows to make the database deployments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows - Flyway Snowflake setup**

download flyway and extract to `c:\tools\flyway`

set environment variable

`FLYWAY_HOME=c:\tools\flyway`

create folder

```
mkdir c:\dev\db-migration\sql
cd c:\dev\db-migration\sql
```

create file `V1.1__create_table_person.sql` with content

```
create table person(
  id number,
  full_name varchar2(30)
);
```

open command prompt and run below commands

```
set SNOWFLAKE_USERNAME=<ENTER YOUR SNOWFLAKE_USERNAME>
set SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD=<ENTER YOUR SNOWFLAKE PASSWORD>
set FLYWAY_VERSION=0.0
set FLYWAY_FOLDER_LOCATION=./sql/

set 
FLYWAY_LICENSE_KEY=<ENTER YOUR LICENCE KEY>

set FLYWAY_URL="jdbc:snowflake://<YOUR ACCOUNT URL>/?warehouse=<ENTER WAREHOUSE NAME>&db=<ENTER DB NAME>&JDBC_QUERY_RESULT_FORMAT=JSON"

flyway -licenseKey=%FLYWAY_LICENSE_KEY% info -url=%FLYWAY_URL% -user=%SNOWFLAKE_USERNAME% -password=%SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD% -locations="filesystem:%FLYWAY_FOLDER_LOCATION%" -baselineOnMigrate=true -baselineVersion="%FLYWAY_VERSION%"
```

output

```
+------------+---------+------------------------+------+--------------+---------+----------+
| Category   | Version | Description            | Type | Installed On | State   | Undoable |
+------------+---------+------------------------+------+--------------+---------+----------+
| Versioned  | 1.1     | create table person    | SQL  |              | Pending | No       |
+------------+---------+------------------------+------+--------------+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer @Bikram gave, some additional information on Flyway's Snowflake support can be found in the Flyway documentation.
https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/snowflake-184127607.html